# Project Euler #10 and #12 in Java - Prime Numbers

Tags: java, programming-challenge, primes

I am dealing with a huge time taking with primes. I hope you know they are pretty random and that's why create many problem. Both are using the same logic/methods.

```
/*
 * The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17. Find the sum of all
 * the primes below two million.
 * http://projecteuler.net/problem=10
 */

public static long get10() {
    long sum = 0;// 2 is also a prime
    for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
/*
 * The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural
 * numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 =
 * 28. The first ten terms would be:
 * 
 * 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
 * 
 * Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
 * 
 * 1: 1 3: 1,3 6: 1,2,3,6 10: 1,2,5,10 15: 1,3,5,15 21: 1,3,7,21 28:
 * 1,2,4,7,14,28 We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have
 * over five divisors.
 * 
 * What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred
 * divisors?
 * http://projecteuler.net/problem=12
 */ 
public static long get12() {
    for (int i = 1;; i++) {
        long n_t = Sumk(i);
        int d = getDivisorCount(n_t);
        if (d >= 500) {
            return n_t;
        }
    }
}
public static long Sumk(int n) {
    // Sum of k from 1 to n =n*(n+1)/2 [Also n'th triangular number]
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 2)
        return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

public static int getDivisorCount(long n) {
    int d = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n;) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            int d2 = 0;
            while (n % i == 0) {
                ++d2;
                n /= i;
            }               
            d *= (d2 + 1);
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            ++i;
        } else {
            i += 2;
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

Currently the output is:

**10**

> Time taken 4.160109858 seconds

**12**

> Time taken 6.856344169 seconds

Comment: These are two different problems. You can reuse some of the machinery, but the machinery needed to solve the second problem is overkill in solving the first problem. The first problem should take a few milliseconds. The second, a second or two.

Comment: Correction: The second problem should only take a few tens of milliseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which would give you all the speed you need. There's a lot of such code here on CR, so let's gop to the review.

```
long sum = 0;// 2 is also a prime
for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++) {
```

Right, but

```
long sum = 1;// 2 is also a prime
for (int i = 3; i < 2000000; i+=2) {
```

does the job as well. No big improvement as the evens get tested very fast.

```
    long n_t = Sumk(i);
```

This is a terrible name, but maybe OK in math code.

```
    int d = getDivisorCount(n_t);
```

What do we know about divisors of a product? Right, you could simply "add" them.<sup>1</sup> No advantage here, but a big speed up for big numbers (coming in later Euler problems).

As you count the divisors of `a * (a+1)` and then `(a+1) * (a+2)`, you could reuse the divisors for `(a+1)` for a speedup factor of 2.

```
public static long Sumk(int n) {
```

Method names always start with lowercase.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 2)
        return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

That's fine. Just note that `(i & 1)` is a faster way of computing `i % 2` for non-negative `i`.

```
public static int getDivisorCount(long n) {
    int d = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n;) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
```

*And that's the culprit! You're doing an expensive operation (`isPrime`) in order to save a much cheaper one (division)!*

---

Actually, the whole method is confusing, so let's go through:

```
public static int getDivisorCount(long n) {
    int d = 1;
```

But `d` is not a nice name. I'd suggest to call it simply `result`.

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= n;) {
```

Here, you could use a test like i * i < n again, couldn't you?

```
        if (isPrime(i)) {
```

My above point was about efficiency. Actually, in order for the below computation (`d *= (d2 + 1)`) to work, it's necessary to use only primes here. However,

- when you get a divisor of the (reduced) `n` here
- it's always the least divisor
- and the least multiple is always a prime

  ```
          int d2 = 0;
          while (n % i == 0) {
              ++d2;
              n /= i;
          }               
          d *= (d2 + 1);
      }
      if (i == 2) {
          ++i;
      } else {
          i += 2;
      }
  ```

That's OK, but I'd handle `2` specially. There's a nice trick (irrelevant here) for getting out all powers of two:

```
int d2 = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(n);
n >>= d2;
```

```
    }
    return d;
}
```

OK. Btw., my solutions to these problems take nearly one second. That's not fast, but I don't care as there's enough to optimize when working on the harder problems.

### My divisorCount

It takes 0.12 seconds and could surely be improved via memoization or a precomputed list of primes (a list up to `Math.sqrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` can be easily found in internet).

```
private int divisorCount(int x) {
    int result = 1;
    {
        final int d2 = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(x);
        result *= d2 + 1;
        x >>= d2;
    }
    for (int i=3; i*i <= x; i+=2) {
        int d2 = 0;
        while (x%i == 0) {
            ++d2;
            x /= i;
        }
        result *= d2 + 1;
    }
    if (x!=1) result *= 2;
    return result;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I was wrong here. The prime factors list (multiset) can simply be concatenated. The number of divisors can be computed easily using them. Let's say that this is what I meant by "add" (it's not, I was plain wrong, but don't tell it further).

Comment: why is the value of n in x=2^n... same as number of trailing zeroes. for example take 400=2^4.5^2 see trailing zeroes=2, n=4? I am misunderstanding, not I?

Comment: @ADG It's all binary, not decimal. So `400` is `0x190` which is `1_1001_0000` in binary. Four trailing zeros, right?

Comment: Ok got it finally as: "Answer is 76576500, Time taken 0.134982883 seconds" I used sieving to decrease it too.